# How dump table with partitions to single file as one table?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, pg-dump

I need to make a dump main table  with tables-partitions in one file. Is it possible to do this with some commands in postgresql console or with pg_dump?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. It will recreate the table AND partitions :

```
 pg_dump --username=uname -t "table_name" --file=filename.sql db_name
```